# Email on form submission using Power Automate which includes file upload

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-forms

I've got a very simple workflow that on submission of a Microsoft form emails me the contents.

One of the optional fields is for users to upload a photo.

I would love for the file to be attached to the email, but I would settle for just a "File uploaded? Yes/no" so I can know if  need to dig into MS forms to get the file manually.

So far all the things I've tried either return blank or constantly "false" (so incorrect).

Pretty new to power automate, and migrating over from SharePoint 2013 workflows so apologies if this is a really basic question.